# how to query this data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

So, the data is look like that:

```
{"_id":"asfasbasdf123", session:"lastAccess:1002040506, myd:'ataber244' "}
```

lastAccess is the Date.  the number is the UTC date number.

how should I query for data that with "lastAccess" date less than certain days?
 the lastAccess in part of the string in the "session" variable.

Thanks.

- By the way, I mean command line.

Comment: which language are you using to query? from JavaScript?

Comment: I use command line.  but also probably need a solution with node.js with mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

So the first big question is *"why is session a string"*.

```
{"_id":"asfasbasdf123", session:"lastAccess:1002040506, myd:'ataber244' "}
```

As written, I don't know of any simply query. You basically have to do a Regular Expression and then perform a comparison, but this is not trivial.

Is it possible to do the following:

```
{"_id":"asfasbasdf123", session: { lastAccess: 1002040506, myd: 'ataber244' }}
```

If so, then you can do the following:

```
db.sessions.find( { 'session.lastAccess' : { $lt: your_timestamp } } )
```

Comment: Sigh.. I'm using connect-mongo  datastore.   data are stored as string.  that's why.. it is kinda out of my control.   If it is not a string, but an object, I know what to do and less headache.. :(

Comment: You can write a map-reduce function that will pull out session, parse it as json, convert the last access to the right datetime format then do comparisons.

Comment: Actually, I want to delete the records that are older than certain days.  so Map Reduce may not work if I remove record.  :(